# Order of if and draw statements

Tags: javascript

While solving - [this problem](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming/logic-if-statements/pc/challenge-your-first-painting-app), the code that works is

```
draw = function() {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
  }
};
```

Why can't we call the draw function under if statement -

```
if (mouseIsPressed) {
  draw = function() {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
  };
}
```

to get the same result?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reverse the order"?

Comment: @mrJoe I meant call the draw function under if statement

Comment: because then you would define the function only when "mouseIsPressed", but not once, every time you press the mouse. And you would then overwrite the previously defined function.

Comment: @mrJoe that is not possible. It is an interactive environment

Comment: What's not possible? Editing the question?

Comment: @mrJoe Adding more code - the code is complete in the question. And the question is understandable too

Comment: He posted only the working version. If he added the code he expects to work (but it doesn't) there wouldn't be and doubts about it.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I was confused because you talked about calling the `draw` function while in fact you don't call it neither if the first nor in the second example.

Comment: @mrJoe, the interactive environment is calling draw on mousemove - that code is not available to OP

Comment: I know this. I viewed the question on my mobile device and didn't bother to open khanacademy.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge provides you with a method `draw` defined to draw an ellipse.  As seen in the demo, moving your mouse in the canvas area draws an ellipse at every possible moment.

If you were to surround the entire definition of draw like this:

```
if (mouseIsPressed) {
   draw = function() {
      ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
   };
}
```

Essentially you're placing a condition on whether or not `draw` is even *defined* based on at the time of definition, the mouse was pressed.  Or to think of it another way, `draw` is the function getting called, so if it weren't defined, it would never get called.  The *content* of `draw` determines what does (or does not *hint hint*) get done when this event happens.

Though I'll also add that there is an actual event for mouse click.  This is probably outside the scope of the challenge, but just to mention that if you were to implement this, you wouldn't limit drawing circles in case of mouse not pressed, but rather you'd *only* draw circles on mouse click event instead.